# Display an image stored in a variable inside a constant

Tags: javascript, html, image, constants

The following code is just a part of my original code.

I have several constants like this one.

Each variable will be displayed as a  element.

What I need is to display every image stored in all the variables Imagem with the simplest code as possible.

```
const jogos2018 = {
  LSB_2018_JOGO_1: {
    Data: "11/03/2018",
    Hora: "15:00",
    Imagem: "<img src='Imagens/oponentes/basquetebol/lsb/bmc.png' />",
    Oponente: "BMC",
    Placar: "V, 52-42",
    Torneio: "LSB",
    Temporada: "Regular",
    Local: "Ginásio Miécimo da Silva",
    Mais: "Mais+"
  }
};
```

Comment: Store them in array or object

Comment: Out of interest, do you have any control over the objects? Do they have to be separate variables / objects? Otherwise I would store every image in one array / object (or patch them together first), before looping over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var items = Object.values(jogos2018)
var parentElement = document.body // You may change this to any other element

for (let item of items)
{
    parentElement.innerHTML += item.Imagem
}
```

This code is for demonstrations only, meaning:

- This code is NOT efficient
- Further adjustments required to suit your needs

Please refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and check the document `createElement` method to get the general concept of doing it right (pure `JS`, no `jQuery`)

Answer (score 1):

Code could be much cleaner / performing but should get you going.

I assume your jogos2018 is an object that contains an array of objects represented by incremental properties suffixed as LSB_2018_JOGO_x or similar.

It also seems they are already doing the markup for you so all you need to do is collect those and output the html.

```js
const jogos2018 = {
  LSB_2018_JOGO_1: {
    Data: "11/03/2018",
    Hora: "15:00",
    Imagem: "<img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549223123-e05d6e08643d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60' />",
    Oponente: "BMC",
    Placar: "V, 52-42",
    Torneio: "LSB",
    Temporada: "Regular",
    Local: "Ginásio Miécimo da Silva",
    Mais: "Mais+"
  },
  LSB_2018_JOGO_2: {
    Data: "11/03/2018",
    Hora: "15:00",
    Imagem: "<img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549018404-766c8a1fe5c3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60' />",
    Oponente: "BMC",
    Placar: "V, 52-42",
    Torneio: "LSB",
    Temporada: "Regular",
    Local: "Ginásio Miécimo da Silva",
    Mais: "Mais+"
  }
}

const fillme = document.querySelector('#fillme')


const filler = arr => {
  let images = ''

  for (let prop in arr) {
    images += arr[prop].Imagem
  }

  return images
}



fillme.innerHTML = filler(jogos2018)
```

```html
<div id="fillme"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.stringify()` to convert the JavaScript plain object to a `JSON` string, then `.match()` the property name and value, `.split()` the property name

```js
const jogos2018 = {"LSB_2018_JOGO_1":{"Data":"11/03/2018","Hora":"15:00","Imagem":"<img src='Imagens/oponentes/basquetebol/lsb/bmc.png' />","Oponente":"BMC","Placar":"V, 52-42","Torneio":"LSB","Temporada":"Regular","Local":"Ginásio Miécimo da Silva","Mais":"Mais+"}};

const getProp = (o, prop) => 
  JSON.stringify(o)
  .match(new RegExp(`"${prop}":"[^"]+(?=")`)).pop()
  .split(/^.*:"/).pop();

console.log(getProp(jogos2018, "Imagem"));
```